# Load only one row from an endpoint response using a TypeScript array

Tags: angular, typescript

I currently have this array and load function which will load all items in the array. This works fine.

```
results:  myArray[]

load() {
  this.myService.getData().subscribe((response) => {
  const searchModel = new SearchResultsModel(response);

  this.results = searchModel.results;
});
}
```

I would like to get only a specific item based on the id. I would like to change `this.results`
to

```
  this.results = searchModel.results.find(x => x.id === 123456);
```

When I try to to do this I get an error that says:

> Type 'myArray' is missing the following properties from myArray[]:
> length, pop, push, concat and 28 others.

What would I need to do to correct this?

_________ Update _________

I got some TypeScript advice from a co-worker and got it to work like this:

```
import { find } from 'lodash';

this.results = [find(searchModel.results, { id: 123456 })];
```

results is being used as the datasource for a datagrid I'm using and this datagrid takes an array as input. Since the find returns an Object it had to be cast to an Array.

Comment: If you only want one item why _is_ the property typed as an array of them?

Comment: That is a good question. I haven't really thought about how many records there will be but I just wanted to try getting only one.

Comment: Well either the type or the value is wrong, we can't tell you which. The compiler is doing exactly what it's supposed to. Maybe you want filter instead of find, or maybe you want to change the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need `lodash` for that. This will do the trick:

```js
// ...
const result = searchModel.results.find(x => x.id === 123456);
this.results = [ result ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
load() {
 this.myService.getData().subscribe((response) => {
  const searchModel = new SearchResultsModel(response);
  this.results = searchModel.results.map(x => x.id === 123456);
 });
}
```

Comment: That would give you an array where all of the values are the one with that ID repeated as many times as the length of all the results. How does that make any sense?!

Comment: This does get the id I was looking for, but it gets it 35 times.

Comment: i edited my answer. i'm in a train and i wrote my answers on my phone:)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "myArray" type is incorrect, hard to say with only this info. I'd suggest to try something like

```
type MyArray = Array<typeof SearchResultsModel>;

class YourClass {
  results: MyArray;
  .
  .
  .
}
```